# How to redirect input as password from a file to dial a vpn connection

Tags: vpn

VPNBook provides fastest vpn service but they changes password about every week. So, i want to call password from a file instead of editing batch file every time, i have tried many ways but doesn't work. please someone correct this script

```
@echo off
:START
set u=vpnbook
set p=<%systemdrive%\pass.txt
rasdial us1.vpnbook.com %u% %p%
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1
goto END
:END
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where almost right.

You need to change the `set p=...` line with `set /p p=<%systemdrive%\pass.txt`.

Note the extra `/p`.